# Check for file/subdirectory existence with VB.NET using FtpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a problem with my FTP upload and I hope you can help me. I'm trying create folders and then upload files to them. What my program should do is checking if a folder already exists, and if not, create a new one with the name checked before. The program runs fine, except for the error described below.

My Problem:
I want to upload a folder called `ghandle` -> works as intended.
After that, I want to upload a folder called `handle` -> doesn't work, because the `.Contains` method that checks the folders on the FTP server, finds `ghandle` and stops, because `ghandle` contains `handle`.

Are there other options like `.Contains` which will just check for whole words or exact matches?

Here is my source code:

```
Dim dirname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialogHtml.FileName) & "_files"    
Dim ftp = "ftp://" & ftp_address.Text & "/"
Dim user = ftp_user.Text
Dim pass = ftp_password.Text

Dim request As Net.FtpWebRequest = Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(ftp)
Dim creds As Net.NetworkCredential = New Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass)
request.Credentials = creds

Dim resp As Net.FtpWebResponse = Nothing
request.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
request.KeepAlive = True
Using resp
    resp = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
    Dim s As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    If Not s.Contains(dirname) Then
        request = Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(ftp & dirname)
        request.Credentials = creds
        request.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
        resp = request.GetResponse()
        MsgBox("Created folder " & dirname)
    Else
        MsgBox("Folder " & dirname & " already exists!")
    End If
End Using
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `ListDirectory`, not `ListDirectoryDetails`. The `ListDirectory` returns plain names only, what is enough for your purpose and easy to parse.

Then just split the output to an array of individual file names, using the [`String.Split` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split#system-string-split(system-char()-system-stringsplitoptions)):

```
Dim names As String() =
    sr.ReadToEnd().Split(
        New Char() {vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

And use the [`IEnumerable.Contains` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains#system-linq-enumerable-contains-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-0)) to check for given file name:

```
If Not names.Contains(dirname) Then
```